# Check if annotation processing or usual runtime in Java

Tags: java, annotation-processing

Is there any technique in Java to check if annotation processing or usual runtime (or some other kind of processing) is taking place?

For example something like this:

```
if(Processing.isAnnotationProcessing()) {
    ...
}
```

Or something like ...

```
if(Processing.getProcessingContext() == ProcessingContext.ANNOTATION_PROCESSING) {
    ...
}
```

So I am looking for a possibility to check this anywhere in the code.
Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? How frequently do you need to check? Can you get a stack trace and look for some class in the call chain?

Comment: I want to change the behavior of some utility method. I will update the question for the purpose. I need it just once for now but it would be fine to do it in a static code block.
I also thought about checking the stack trace but that might be a quite expensive lookup in some cases.

Comment: it might be expensive, but you can cache it.

Comment: That's true and it seems to be the only way.
I just found out that I could just catch javax.lang.model.type.MirroredTypeException to achieve what I need.
So my problem got solved differently. 
I'll wait some time and maybe there is coming an answer, because I think it would be interesting to know if the thing asked in the question is possible.
But I will delete it shortly if an answer is left out.